# Divide a irregular format mesh into two parts

Tags: mesh

I got a doubt on what is the best method for me to select the left part of this mesh to divide this into two since this is a half-circle mesh.
I am looking at the options and cannot believe this has to be done point by point to then cut the object into two. The reason for this is that I have two different textures to apply, one on the interior part of this "arch" and another on the outside.
Like you can see I didn't do it right this time and some got selected on the other side

[image]

How can I in a fast way select the left part divide it and close it and then the right and do the same process?

Thanks
Ilda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have suitable topology, and can <kbd>Alt</kbd> - select an edge-loop, then one of the many selection options open to you is:

Header Menu  *> Select > Select Loops > Select Loop Inner-Region.*..

[image]

.. and you can decide which side is inner, and which is outer, if they're both the same size.

Comment: Very elegant. Now I want to know how Blender decides which side is bigger or inner on a cube :))

Comment: This is perhaps dumb question, how do I close the inner and the outer parts since they are hollow?

Comment: @JachymMichal Since I am very lazy, and there are only two choices, I haven't given that one a lot of thought :) Leave it to the theorists..

Comment: @RobinBetts The technique you've shown was spot on! I am just starting out and I can wait for tomorrow for sure :)

Comment: @IldaLontaria Believe it or not, the 'dumb' question has options. 1. Do you _need_ to expose the internal faces? (Not necessary, just to give the outside different textures). 2 If so, do you want the seam between the 2 halves to show, or to magically disappear when they are joined, as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/fJ3IYMl)?

Comment: @RobinBetts, the image you've uploaded was what I was looking for to do, to maybe hide the seams there since the UV is chaotic right now like you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/XiB2Scw)

Comment: Hiding the seams in the geometry is not the same as hiding the seams in UV, I can't tell from your picture exactly what you're after.. but I take it you _do_ need to make the halves look solid when they are separated?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance I haven't forgotten all about you, was hoping to know if you needed the separated halves to look solid.. :)